# Summernote dropdown doesn't work with Bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap framework for navbar and now I wanna use summernote WYSIWYG HTML editor.

If I import `bootstrap.min.js` script, navbar dropdown menu works perfectly, but dropdown in summernote not (color choose etc.).

If I remove this script, summernote works, but navbar dropdown not. I also remove `jquery.min.js` and create own script for add class open to dropdown-toggle because with `jquery.min.js` summernote don't appear.

Any solution for navbar and summernote dropdown function?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$("#yourid").summernote();
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all these answers but this worked for me :

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote-lite.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that jQuery and Bootstrap are only being loaded once

Answer (score 1):

try that, i think you could be able to solve it by `css`

```
  .dropdown-menu > li > a {
           display: block;
            padding: 3px 20px;
            clear: both;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            color: #333;
            white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, It was solved by replacing bootstrap version use this

```
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the below code as it works perfectly for me

```
let buttons = $('.note-editor button[data-toggle="dropdown"]');
    
    buttons.each((key, value)=>{
      $(value).on('click', function(e){
        $(this).attr('data-bs-toggle', 'dropdown')
        console.log()
        ata('id', 'dropdownMenu');
      })
    })
```

Comment: It is work me, but need double click. I also don't know that what is ```ata('id', 'dropdownMenu') ``` ?

Answer (score 1):

For After initializing, run this.

IN JS

```
let buttons = $('.note-editor button[data-toggle="dropdown"]');

buttons.each((key, value)=>{
  $(value).on('click', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.note-btn-group').toggleClass('open');
  })
})
```

Comment: IN CSS


.note-btn-group.open .note-dropdown-menu, .note-dropdown-item {
    display: block;
}
.note-dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    padding: 5px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
}

Answer (score 0):

in summernote.css file
find

```
.panel-heading.note-toolbar{padding:0 0 5px 5px;margin:0;}
```

change to

```
.panel-heading.note-toolbar{padding:0 0 5px 5px;margin:0;overflow-y: unset;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your jquery version. jQuery for summernote should be upper than 3.0.0.